# MySQL Stored Procedures `Error Code: 1064` at Runtime

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, dynamic-sql, mysql-8.0, information-schema

I am getting this error message and I assumed that the error is somewhere in this syntax `''ABC Company ORDER BY Total ASC  LIMIT 0, 1000)'`.

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near ''Column_1  ORDER BY Total ASC  LIMIT 0, 1000)' at line 22
```

To give you the background, here's the stored procedure code for that error:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `proc_column_sum`()
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
    SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE table2 (Vendor VARCHAR(100), Total DECIMAL(10,2)) AS (',
        GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT ''',COLUMN_NAME,''' Vendor, SUM(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`) Total 
        FROM testdb.products' SEPARATOR '\n UNION ALL \n'),
        '\n ORDER BY Total ASC', 
        '\n LIMIT 0, 20)'
    )
    INTO @sql
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testdb' 
        AND TABLE_NAME   = 'products'
        AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'name');
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

In my debugging, it is surprisingly that the stored procedure runs with no issues if the `products` table has 5 columns only. It returns syntax error when `products` table reach 6 or more rows already.

I really do not know what is wrong with my codes above. All my variable columns int `products` table are readable and does not contain any unique characters. It just so happened that on 6 or more rows on my `product` table it automatically returned an error 1064.

I also suspect that the error is this part of the code `''',COLUMN_NAME,'''`.

Can anyone check what's wrong my my code above?

**UPDATE 1:** @sql debug result and you will find the error at the last 3 row from the bottom

```
SELECT 'Quia soluta molliti
ORDER BY Total ASC
LIMIT 0, 1000)
```

Here's the complete result of @sql. Bear with me the column_names here are random:

```
CREATE TABLE best_vendors (Vendor VARCHAR(100), Total DECIMAL(10,2)) AS (SELECT 'Reiciendis eos nostrum ut sequi.' Vendor, SUM(`Reiciendis eos nostrum ut sequi.`) Total 
        FROM project_x.canvass_prices
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Sed quidem aspernatur quisquam ut.' Vendor, SUM(`Sed quidem aspernatur quisquam ut.`) Total 
        FROM project_x.canvass_prices
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Aut dolorem repellendus iste nisi...' Vendor, SUM(`Aut dolorem repellendus iste nisi...`) Total 
        FROM project_x.canvass_prices
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Eius perspiciatis iure pariatur.' Vendor, SUM(`Eius perspiciatis iure pariatur.`) Total 
        FROM project_x.canvass_prices
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Qui aut dolore sit.' Vendor, SUM(`Qui aut dolore sit.`) Total 
        FROM project_x.canvass_prices
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Voluptas et fugit itaque.' Vendor, SUM(`Voluptas et fugit itaque.`) Total 
        FROM project_x.canvass_prices
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Est perspiciatis incidunt non.' Vendor, SUM(`Est perspiciatis incidunt non.`) Total 
        FROM project_x.canvass_prices
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Quia soluta molliti
 ORDER BY Total ASC
 LIMIT 0, 1000)
```

Comment: Try using `SELECT \`'` there

Comment: To debug this, use `SELECT @sql;` instead of preparing and executing the query.

Comment: Or try  `... GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT " ',COLUMN_NAME,' " Vendor ...`

Comment: @Barmar I have updated my question (UPDATE 1) with debug `@sql` result and you will find the error at the bottom. I do not know how to fix this type of error. So weird to me that it happens this way.

Comment: You need to increase the [`@group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) setting.

Comment: @Barmar It works! But what would be the effect if I used the maximum length 64 bit value = 18446744073709551615?

Comment: No effect unless you have a runaway group_concat that tries to use huge amounts of memory.

Comment: I see that would be great! Thank you so much. Can you post your answer so I can mark this question answered.